# Definition of evolution equation in Rovelli's quantum gravity book or how a function can determine a curve

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, differential-geometry, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

I'm reading the book Quantum Gravity by Carlo Rovelli. In page 107, he says that the evolution equation of the system can be cast into $f=0$, where $f$ is a map such that $f: \mathcal{C}\times \Gamma \rightarrow V$ And $V$ is a linear space. When we have no gauge symmetry $V={R}$ and rovelli says $f$ determines a curve (a one dimensional submanifold) in $\mathcal{C}$ (fix a point in $\Gamma$). Note that $\mathcal{C}$ is the space of partial observables and $\Gamma$ is the space of solutions.

However, as far as I can see, $f=0$ determines a hypersurface in $\mathcal{C}$ (a manifold with codimension 1). On the other hand, it is clear for me if I solve the Hamilton's equations from the start and project the solution to $\mathcal{C}$ we finish with a curve. I am confused. How $f=0$ can result a curve?

Comment: I have looked at page 107 of Quantum Gravity by Carlo Rovelli and found nothing of the sorts. Could you please attach a link?

Comment: Also I can imagine $f$ to be equal to zero only on some 1-dimensional curve. Why do you think that it has to be a subsurface?

Comment: Look this http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~rovelli/book.pdf. In this format (draft) it's in page 75 where Rovelli states the three part of a general dynamical system.

Comment: I can't understand how $f=0$ can define a curve. It obviously can't I think. For example consider $f:R^3 \rightarrow R$ and define $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1$. Therfore $f=0$ defines a sphere in $R^3$.

Comment: consider $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2$. It obviously defines a curve (straight line $x=0, y=0$).

Comment: I don't find in Rovelli's book your satement that $V = \mathbb R$ for gauge-free spaces. And he explicitly states that motion can have dimension $k>1$, and those are the gauge symmetries on the motion.